# Need to increment the cell but only on n+7 row in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is the formula :

```
=IF(A674=1,CONCATENATE(Sheet1!A7,"(",Sheet1!B7,")"),0)
```

where, when I  am pasting this formula on every n+7 row, the value is incrementing by 7(obviously). I need to paste this formula but increment by only one on every n+7 row.

PS: This task if from company where i am involved in making the test case for my development, but there are around 1200 objects :(.

Answer (score 0):

To get incrementation of one for every 7 rows, divide row number by 7 and round up. For example:

```
=ROUNDUP(ROW(A1)/7, 0)
```

The above formula will return 1 for range A1:A7, 2 for range A8:A14, etc. - use it within your formula to get the desired incrementation.

Comment: Shouldn't there be any `IF(MOD(ROW(A1),7)=0, ...)` in order not to repeat this constantly?